# Laravel open url in server side after action

Tags: laravel, sms

is there any way to open url in "server side".

I'm using https://www.lightsms.com/ as my sms gateway. And to send sms, you need to visit (for example) https://www.lightsms.com/send.php, so i don't want to redirect user to that url. I just want to open it in server background, and close.

after route and before real redirect, example's here:

```
Route::get('/sms', function() {
//i need to excecute that url here
redirect('success.html');
});
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this asynchronously using xhr or ajax if you use jquery, you basically post the information asynchronously and your server (your php script) just returns a json back, in your success function / promise you can get the data and do something with it if you like, this process does not require any redirect.

This is a simple example which you may need to modify:

```
function asyncPost(event){
   $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.lightsms.com/send.php",
        data: {
            name: "any value or variable," 
            id: "any value or variable"
        },
        datatype: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) { 
            console.log("success");
            // do something with data if you need, data contains the returned data from your php script
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log("an error occured");
        }
   });
}
```